# iOnic list not refreshing after adding a new item to the list using web service

Tags: list, ionic-framework

We have a iOnic based project and during check out users can add new address to their account. [image]

This is what my controller file look like

```
$scope.addAddress = function() {
            $scope.showLoading();
            addressService.addUserAddress($scope.userDetails.userID, $scope.addAddressdata.houseNo, $scope.addAddressdata.street, $scope.addAddressdata.AddDesc, $scope.addAddressdata.LID)
                .success(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.hideLoading();
                    $scope.closeModal();
                    $scope.getAllAddress();  
                });
        };
        $scope.getAllAddress = function() {
            addressService.getAllLocations()
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.locations = response;
                    $scope.hideLoading();
                });
        };
```

And this is what my services file look like

```
    function() {
    "use strict";

    var myApp = angular.module('jobolo');
    myApp.service('addressService', ['$http', 'appVariableService', function($http, appVariableService) {
        var addressService = this;

        addressService.getAllLocations = function() {
            var data = {
                appid: appVariableService.get('appId')
            };
            return $http.post(appVariableService.get('baseURL') + 'useraddress/getMyLocation', data);
        };
        addressService.getUserAddress = function(userId) {

            return $http.get(appVariableService.get('baseURL') + 'useraddress/myaddress/' + userId, {cache:false});
        };
        addressService.addUserAddress = function(userId, houseNo, street, adddesc, lid) {
            var data = {
                appid: appVariableService.get('appId'),
                userid: userId,
                houseno: houseNo,
                street: street,
                adddesc: adddesc,
                lid: lid,
            };
            return $http.post(appVariableService.get('baseURL') + 'useraddress/adAdd' , data);
        };

    }]);


})();
```

When I add a new address it does add to the database but isn't showing in list. I tried adding $scope.refreshList(); to the code too. When I log out and come back it does show up. Thank you for your help in advance

**View Codes are**

```
<ion-view class="main-content">
<ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
    <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<div class="bar bar-subheader">
    <h2 class="title">Select Address</h2>
</div>
<ion-content class="has-subheader" scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" style="bottom:57px">
    <div class="list">
        <ion-radio 
            ng-model="data.selectedAddress" 
            ng-value="address" 
            ng-repeat="address in userAddresses" 
            class="radio-nowrap"
            >
            House No. {{address.HouseNo}}, {{address.Street}}, {{address.AddDesc}}, {{address.AreaName}}, {{address.City}}
        </ion-radio>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="row">
        <div class="col location-form">
            <button class="button" type="button" ng-click="openModal()">Add New Address</button>
        </div>
    </div> -->
</ion-content>
<div class="row" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;padding:0">
    <div class="col location-form">
        <button class="button" type="button" ng-click="openModal()">Add New Address</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col location-form">
        <button class="button" type="button" ng-disabled="!data.selectedAddress" ng-click="selectAddress(data.selectedAddress)">Select Address</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you write your view code.

Comment: @egvrcn view codes added

Comment: I think you should empty in userAddresses data each binding.

Comment: @egvrcn can you please suggest codes?

Comment: I cant see your $scope.userAddresses binding in your codes. Can you write this code.

Comment: Have you tried with `scope.$apply();` ? http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html